# PUT http://localhost:3000/events/undefined 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, api, vuex

this code updates a specific object by taking it's id. when i hard code the id into the API cal, there is no error and it works just fine, but when i pass the id that it gets from the component in a new argument into the 'updateEvent' function it returns undefined id.
i think the problem is inside the vuex code inside the parameters that I'm passing

axios API call

```
updateEvent(id, event) {
        return apiClient.put(`/events/${id}`, event)
}
```

and in vuex actions

```
updateEvent({
      commit,
      dispatch
    }, {
      id,
      event
    }) {
      return EventService.updateEvent(id, event)
        .then(() => {
          commit('UPDATE_EVENT', event)
        })
    }
```

and I dispatched it inside my component like this

```
methods: {
    updateEvent() {
      this.$store
        .dispatch("updateEvent", this.id, this.event)
        .then(() => {
          this.$router.push({
            name: "EventShow",
            params: { id: this.id },
          });
        })
        .catch(() => {});
    },
  }
```

Comment: The vuex code shown is not valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your action [unpacks/destructures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) `id` and `event` from the payload (the 2nd argument), but your dispatch is not passing an object. Instead, it's passing `this.id` -- presumably a `String`, which does not contain a property named `id` or `event` (hence, `id` resolves to "undefined" in your URL).

To resolve the problem, your dispatch should pass an *object* with the expected properties:

```js
//this.$store.dispatch("updateEvent", this.id, this.event); // DON'T DO THIS
this.$store.dispatch("updateEvent", { id: this.id, event: this.event })
```